# Getting the string value of each leaf using //leaf

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, netbeans

Here is a tree:

```
<tree id="alphabet">
    <root>
        <node id="node1">
            <leaf>A</leaf>
            <leaf>B</leaf>
        </node>
        <node id="node2">
            <leaf>C</leaf>
            <leaf>D</leaf>
        </node>
    </root>
</tree>
```

Here is an XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="//leaf"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

All XPath material says the double slash (//leaf) expression should select all leaf elements throughout the document.
However, in this case, only the first leaf (A) gets copied to the output, and not its siblings.
When instead we apply the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="leaf">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <br/>
    </xsl:template>
```

The content of all 4 leaf elements are copied to output, as expected.
Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a XSLT/XPath 1.0 stylesheet:

The `value-of` in the first case turns the nodeset of all `leaf` elements into a string and this operation only uses the [first node](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions):

> A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of
>   the node in the node-set that is first in document order. If the
>   node-set is empty, an empty string is returned.

In the second case you are applying the `value-of` to every `leaf` node.

But with a XSLT/XPath 2.0 processor (and using `version='2.0'` on the stylesheet) the `value-of` in the first case would produce the output `A B C D`.